# React Native Async Storage devuelve null

Tags: react-native, async-storage

soy nuevo utilizando React Native, estoy desarrollando mi primera aplicación, y me he topado con un problema al utilizar Async Storage, he implementado el código que esta en la documentación y retorna un JSON con valores nulos, sin embargo el valor de la llave se muestra si se hace a través de un *alert* o *console* dentro de la misma función, pero no se puede asignar a una variable o a un state, el return de la función también devuelve el mismo JSON nulo, aquí el código que utilizo:

```
export default class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { 
          username:"",
      };

      this.getData();// retornara {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}
      
  }

getData = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('username');
      this.state.username = value // state sera null
      console.log(value) // aqui si funciona, muestra lo que hay en "username"
      return value // retornara {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}
    } catch(e) {
      alert("error:"+e)
    }
  }
```

Comment: pudieras agregar donde realizas la llamada??